# Date Difference in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have a Teradata table that has 2 Varchar columns they both have data something like below

Col 1 :`08/09/2017 01:03:20 PM` and similarly other one 
Col 2 :`09/09/2017 01:03:20 PM`

How can I do date Difference

Simple ( col1- col2) is not helping me.

Comment: I Have another question on the same Dataset, the requirement is to Concat the year from the data set with 'FW' and Week. So the result would be eg:-2019FW26. How do I achive this from above example do I convert it to timestamp here also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if you have any control over this table or the ETL it would be advisable to NOT store your timestamps as varchar since you can't subtract two strings no matter how much they might look like a number or a date.

What you'll have to do is cast these two columns to a `TIMESTAMP` specifying the `FORMAT` that they are currently in. Once cast, you can subtract them to get an `INTERVAL` type representing the number of days between the dates.

```
SELECT (CAST('09/09/2017 01:03:20 PM' AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyybhh:mi:ssbt') - CAST('08/09/2017 01:03:20 PM' AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyybhh:mi:ssbt')) DAY(4)
```

Another option would be (after casting to timestamp), shoving these into a `PERIOD()` and finding the `INTERVAL()` of that period:

```
SELECT INTERVAL(PERIOD(CAST('08/09/2017 01:03:20 PM' AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyybhh:mi:ssbt'), NEXT(CAST('09/09/2017 01:03:20 PM' AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyybhh:mi:ssbt')))) DAY(4)
```

The first option will be better performing since there is less monkeying with the data, but if you'll be doing this often it might be a good idea to just store the `PERIOD` type on the table when you load it so you can just do `INTERVAL(my_period_column) DAY(4)` in your SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for Replying. First Option is working for me and I will go with your advice using first Option.Thanks Again

Comment: @VinayakDas There's just one possible issue, If the difference is over 4 days you'll get an *interval overflow error. If the current calculation is what you want and you only need days, you can try `SELECT Cast(Substr('09/09/2017 01:03:20 PM', 1, 10) AS DATE FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyy')
     - Cast(Substr('08/09/2017 01:03:20 PM', 1, 10) AS DATE FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyy')`

Comment: @dnoeth Did you mean "if the difference of days is over 4 digits"? `day(4)` should be good up to `9999` days or around `27` years.

Comment: @JNevill: Of course, should be 4 digits. 27 years is a lot, but you might have a very low/high date indication *infinity* or you simply got bad data